# Finder Sync Badge Extension Handling

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to create a Finder Sync Extension,in yosemite to show badge in files and folder.

I am on the move, but i have no idea how to turn off extension(remove from extensions list in preferences) when my containing application terminate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try it..

Reload Directory in Finder

// Reload Finder (change the word directory to file if updating file)

```
 NSAppleScript * update = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Finder\" to update POSIX directory \"%@\"",path]];

[update executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

Code to Enable Extension (bundle ID)

```
system("pluginkit -e use -i com.xyz.finderExt")
```

Code to Disable Extension (bundle ID)

```
system("pluginkit -e ignore -i com.xyz.finderExt")
```

Comment: Also, if you have problems during development, it helps to restart finder with `$ killall Finder`. Also when you start your application from different locations (e.g. via xcode and later to test via /Applications/yourapp), it might be that several plugins are registered. you can list them with pluginkit, eg: `$ pluginkit -v -m -i com.xyz.finderExt`, then remove them, and then reload pkd with `$ killall -HUP pkd`

Answer (score 2):

code to remove from extensions list in preferences

**pluginkit -r "/Applications/App-name/Contents/Plugins/extension-name.appex"**